# Paginate the daily stats data in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, laravel-5

I have a `RAW` query in `Laravel`

```
$sales = DB::table('orders')
             ->select(DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as date'), 
                      DB::raw('SUM(total_price) AS total_price'), 
                      'created_at')
             ->groupBy('date')
             ->orderBy('date', 'DESC')
             ->paginate(20);
```

I am trying to paginate the result set, but it shows me the following error;

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'date' in 'group statement' 
(SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `orders` group by `date`)
```

The above query works fine and returns me the complete result set when I replace;

`paginate(20)` with `get()`

What is going on?

Comment: please use 'dat` as column or try it with `date` before and after column name to make it work. date is a keyword in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

```
$sales = DB::table('orders')
             ->select(DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as `date`'), 
                      DB::raw('SUM(total_price) AS total_price'), 
                      'created_at')
             ->groupBy('date')
             ->orderBy('date', 'DESC')
             ->paginate(20);
```

Try this code, it should work.

Comment: @baig772 Is it possible for you to check the raw query it's generating for this code.

Comment: Yes I can check without the `paginate()` and it gives me this `"select DATE(created_at) as `dat`, SUM(total_price) AS total_price, `created_at` from `orders` group by `dat` order by `dat` desc"`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.